# react native maps markers not displaying

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, location, marker

I'm trying to display markers on my MapView. I've followed the example, but none of the markers are displaying on the map, although I can center the map and the location indicator displays. I've imported MapView and Marker from react-native-maps. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  constructorprops: any {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        region: defaultRegion,
        markers: [
            {
                coordinate: {
                    latitude: 37.298984,
                    longitude: -122.050362
                },
                title: "Best Place",
                description: "Description1",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                coordinate: {
                    latitude: 37.297803,
                    longitude: -122.050037
                },
                title: "Best Place2",
                description: "Description 2",
                id: 2
            }
        ]
    };
}

centerLocation = () => {};

componentDidMount() {
    this.centerLocation();
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapContainer>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                region={this.state.region}
            />
            <CenterButton centerLocation={this.centerLocation} />
            {this.state.markers.map((marker: any) => (
                <Marker
                    key={marker.id}
                    coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                    title={marker.title}
                    description={marker.description}
                />
            ))}
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: May I know what is the value of defaultRegion? Also try adding intialRegion in MapView like this, initialRegion={this.state.region} and try using MapView.Marker instead of Marker. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @SandipLipane default region is: const defaultRegion = {
  latitude: 37,
  longitude: -122,
  latitudeDelta: 0.003,
  longitudeDelta: 0.003,
}; Also, MapView.Marker doesn't work, it also gives me a ts error of Property 'Marker' does not exist on type MapView.

Comment: as you have added MapView.Marker code outside the MapView, hence it didn't work. I have added working example in the answer below, please try that.

Comment: To me the solution was to just replace `<Marker` with `<MapView.Marker`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please add below code in render function, hope it will help you

```
return (
  <View>
    <MapView
         ref={MapView => (this.MapView = MapView)}
         style={styles.map}
         initialRegion={this.state.region}
         loadingEnabled = {true}
         loadingIndicatorColor="#666666"
         loadingBackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
         moveOnMarkerPress = {false}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         showsCompass={true}
         showsPointsOfInterest = {false}
         provider="google">
         {this.state.markers.map((marker:any)  => (  
              <MapView.Marker
                key={marker.id}
                coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                title={marker.title}
                description={marker.description}
              />
         }
      </MapView>
      <CenterButton
          centerLocation={this.centerLocation} />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: what does make this.state.markers....it is undefined what is there in this state?

Answer (score 8):

your Marker tag should be within the MapView tag, you have closed the MapView tag before putting your Marker tag inside for example

```
<MapView style={styles.map} showsUserLocation={true} region={this.state.region}>
  {this.state.markers.map((marker: any) => (
    <Marker
      key={marker.id}
      coordinate={marker.coordinate}
      title={marker.title}
      description={marker.description}
    />
  ))}
</MapView>
```